# Yet another stuck BB. Help me save my frame!

Tags: repair, bottom-bracket

So I have two bikes and a year ago I went through the challenge of unscrewing a stuck BB. [The solution](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/12883/failing-to-unscrew-bb-what-now) was to put the tool in a vice and twist the frame around it.

Today I have an even more difficult challenge. [My cheaper bike](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/12450/badly-rusted-suspension-fork) is now about 5 years old and has been through dust, mud and salty snow. The BB is rattling and needs to be changed. I tried.

The BB is obviously cheap, **both cups being plastic**. I used the proper tool, put an elongation bar on the wrench, followed [the correct direction for unscrewing](http://www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help/cartridge-bearing-type-bottom-bracket-service-bbt) ... and ruined both of my cups. The wrench just cut through the plastic teeth of the cup.

My BB is of the following type:

[image]

What can I do? I tried drying the cups apart with a soldering iron - which cut through the plastic somehow. Can I inject something inside, that will melt the cups? Can I pour spirits and set it alight, without damaging my aluminum frame and the paint around?

Comment: The BB looks like you could "attack" the notches in the outer, metallic ring with the correct tool. This way, you could at least get one side out.

Comment: @arne, Both cups and the drive-side ring are plastic and smooth. On the picture is not my exact BB.

Comment: Oh, OK. Then at least I don't see a good possibility without damaging the paint job. If you loosen that requirement, you could try blowtorching the cups away...

Comment: @arne, in the end SOMETHING has to be done, I do not want to ditch the frame. The only hard requirement is that the bike is usable i.e. the thread is not damaged. Just ... I do not have easy access to a blowtorch.

Comment: You don't need an acetylene-high-power-turbo-blowtorch. A cheap one from you local hardware store that basically consists of a camping-stove-cartridge with a little burner attached should suffice imho. Beware of the possibly poisonous fumes though.

Comment: Oh and don't let your frame get too hot in the process. You basically only want to melt/burn the plastic. If the frame gets too hot, it might fall apart directly (the "good" failure) or be weakened to a degree that it will fail catastrophically on the first highway overpass or some such.

Comment: The standard plumber's solution is to somehow just cut out the cup.  Exactly how you'd do this is hard to say -- I'd probably have a shot at drilling through it in several places with a small drill bit.  You would, of course, need to avoid gouging the soft aluminum threads too badly, but a few nicks wouldn't hurt so long as you "chased" them afterwards with, eg, an old steel cup.

Comment: @ Daniel R Hicks, Yea, I have a dremel. So burn or chop. I think I'll cry ;(

Comment: Why worry about damaging the threads? If you want the frame that badly then just get it reamed and faced when your done.

Comment: The amount of heat you can deliver with a propane torch isn't going to harm aluminum, so blast away.  But you'll definitely be needing to sand and repaint when you're done.

Comment: Does any of the bottom bracket stick out on either side of the frame the way the cup on the left of your picture does?

Answer (score 1):

I thought about this a little more, and here is what I'd probably attempt:

The cup has a "shoulder" on the inside that retains the bearing cartridge.  Attack the shoulder somehow (break it, use your Dremel, et al) until it's possible to drive out the cartridge from the other end.  Then, with the cartridge out, is should be possible to pry the remainder of the cup out with minimal damage to the threads.

Comment: I'd cut it with a Stanley knife rather than use a Dremel. Slow, but less risk of damaging the threads.